# Why VS doesn't give me the same result as console in DevTools?

Tags: javascript, console

I'm sorry if this questions is being raised but I'm really new to coding and started to have the first difficult issue and can't figure it out. I have write a simple code like this because I have to learn the `return` command:

```
function multiplyByNineFifths (number) {
    return number *(9/5);
};

function getFahrenheit (celcius) {
    return multiplyByNineFifths (celcius) + 32;
};

getFahrenheit(15);
```

but when when I want to run the code in VS it says:

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\Oerd Bej\Desktop\JavaScript
exercises\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.088 seconds`
```

while in DevTools in console it runs perfectly and it gives me the right answer which is 59.

Please can you help me to figure it out what should I do, I have installed node.js and all the necessary plug in in VS but dont know what is wrong or what is the right question that I have to ask in order to understand it well. Every error in VS it breaks my heart

[image]

Comment: I don't think, there is any issue with the code.The issue might be with VS Code IDE itself.
Check out this link: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because logging is a little different in Chrome than in Node. If you type `console.log(3)` in Chrome, it will log `3`, and then the return value of `console.log` which is `undefined` (because `console.log` doesn't return anything). Chrome will always automatically log the function's return value. Node doesn't. It will only log `3`. Node executes the `getFahrenheit` function, but this function doesn't return anything. It just computes a number in memory, that's it, so nothing gets displayed. If you want to see the result of this operation you need to log it with `console.log(getFahrenheit(15))`.